# Error #2038 when uploading videos to Facebook

Tags: actionscript-3, facebook-graph-api, actionscript

Using this simple AIR app to upload images to my facebook account. 
http://code.google.com/p/facebook-actionscript-api/downloads/list
Uploading images works fine using the MediaUpload_AIR example.

I modified by adding browse support for videos.

The videos seem to upload according to the progress event, but when they have finished uploading I get a error #2038 along with a http status code of 400.

Can't figure out what is happening. The video files are under 5MB in size.
Can anyone shed some light?

Comment: You should include the code you use to upload

Answer (score 0):

found the answer

When targeting the facebook graph API with videos you need to use 'me/videos' instead of 'me/photos'

Comment: _“Five minutes of reading documentation can save you hours of trial-and-error …”_

Comment: The so called 'documentation' leaves a lot to be desired. Substitute 'googling and deductive reasoning' for 'reading documentation'

Comment: __One__ look at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#videos, and it’s absolutely totally doubt-free clear … how one (w|c)ould still need “googling and deductive reasoning” for something that’s as much in plain sight as it gets, I don’t know.